# Leer XML con &quot;, &lt; y &gt en Java

Tags: java, xml

Estoy leyendo un XML para guardar la información en java, pero el XML tiene este formato, ¿Cómo podría leerlo?

```
&lt;?xml version=&quot;1.0&quot; encoding=&quot;UTF-8&quot;?&gt;
&lt;usuarios nombre=&quot;jose&quot; &gt; &lt;/usuarios&gt;
```

Normalmente el XML se vería de esta forma,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<usuarios nombre="jose"></usuarios>
```

Comment: ¿Puedes ser mas especifico con tu necesidad? es decir "para guardar la información en java" me deja un amplio de casos en mi mente. También si pudieras compartir el código que empleas seria de mejor ayuda.

Answer (score 0):

Una forma de realizar esto es mediante [Apache Commons Lang](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/), puedes descargarlo desde:

http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/download_lang.cgi

agregar el jar a tu proyecto y usar la clase:

```
import org.apache.commons.lang3.StringEscapeUtils;
```

de esta forma podras usar la clase `StringEscapeUtils` para realizar la decodificacion html, ejemplo:

```
    String myData = "&lt;?xml version=&quot;1.0&quot; encoding=&quot;UTF-8&quot;?&gt;&lt;usuarios nombre=&quot;jose&quot; &gt; &lt;/usuarios&gt;";        
    String decodedString = StringEscapeUtils.unescapeHtml4(myData);        
    System.out.println(decodedString);
```

obtendrías como valor resultante:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><usuarios nombre="jose" > </usuarios>
```